# How to block INSERT under READ_COMMITTED isolation?

Tags: sql, transactions, sql-insert

Given two tables:

- `Company` [`id, name, balance`]
- `Employee` [`id, name, company_id`]

I'd like to delete a company and its dependencies but I cannot do so atomically because in my real project a company has multiple levels of dependencies which would be too complex to squeeze into a single SQL statement. Besides, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598275/14731 I'm not sure a single SQL statement would be atomic.

Instead I do this:

1. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` all employees associated with the company (lock them to prevent modification in mid-transaction)
2. Delete each employee one by one
3. Delete the parent Company.

There is one catch: **how do I prevent new records that reference the Company from being inserted between step 1 and 2?** According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602125/14731 `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` does not block inserts. Ideally I want to place a lock on the Company, not one lock per every kind of dependency that could point to it.

**UPDATE**: 
I've got an idea but I'm not sure whether it makes sense.

If someone wants to insert a new record that points to the Company, they'd likely need to look it up to make sure it exists. If I `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the company before step 1, it should block their reads thereby delaying the subsequent insert. I've got two questions:

1. Does `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` block normal `SELECT` queries? If not, I'd have to ensure that inserting threads always use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` when looking up the Company.
2. Would this approach work?

Comment: Can't you just wrap your deletes in a transaction: begin transaction, delete all employees with one statement, delete parent company, rollback on error else commit, end transaction?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: @LordPeter, nothing prevents another thread from inserting a new employee between the time you delete all employees and the time you delete the company.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm looking for database-agnostic solutions. If that's not possible, feel free to provide database-specific solutions.

Comment: If you are only running two single queries then the chance of a new employee being inserted will be reduced. If it happens then presumably you have FK constraints that will cause the company delete to fail so you will roll back and can try again. Alternatively, just cascade company deletes to take out the "orphaned" employees? Procedural approaches are rarely the right way to go.

Comment: @LordPeter, CASCADE ON DELETE sounds like a good solution assuming someone could answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/14131108/14731

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

1. The thread that inserts new associations should establish a read lock on the Company (using `REPEATABLE_READ` isolation or `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`)
2. The thread that deletes the Company should write lock the row using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.
3. The write lock will wait for all outstanding read locks to be released and will prevent new read locks from being established until the `DELETE` operation is complete.