# MySQL - why one insert locks second insert?

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock

I want to insert row with unique value in non-primary key field. I cannot use unique index (because of NULL values in multiple field index, but it is not important here).

I use INSERT/SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS as an atomic (I hope) operation - see below.

I will describe problem on simplified example:

I have an empty table:

`CREATE TABLE Test (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  A int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

... and 2 sessions with autocommit mode switched off:

In first session I execute:

`INSERT INTO Test (A)
  SELECT A FROM (SELECT 1 AS A) Inn
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT A FROM Test WHERE A = 1 FOR UPDATE);`

In second session I execute:

`INSERT INTO Test (A)
  SELECT A FROM (SELECT 2 AS A) Inn
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT A FROM Test WHERE A = 2 FOR UPDATE);`

As you can see, I'm inserting independent values. But this second session is locked by the first one. Why? Maybe it is because of gap/next-key lock.

How else i can insert records with "manual" avoiding of duplicate keys and without mutual locking?

Default transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE READ and I don't want to change default settings of database, because other applications use it.

Comment: This seems quite a complex way to do an INSERT IGNORE. What is your reason for this approach?

Comment: Because I can have NULLs in some unique index columns. Do you have any idea how else I can insert unique values?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the gap locking for the `SELECT FOR UDPATE`, there are locks with a unique index, gap locks with a non-unique index, and table locks without an index :

[How do I lock on an InnoDB row that doesn't exist yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068686/how-do-i-lock-on-an-innodb-row-that-doesnt-exist-yet)

In addition, InnoDB places locks when using auto_increment to preserve the sequence of keys, which is important during replication.

This is from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) (emphasis mine):

> When accessing the auto-increment counter, InnoDB uses a special
>   table-level AUTO-INC lock that it keeps to the end of the current SQL
>   statement, not to the end of the transaction. The special lock release
>   strategy was introduced to improve concurrency for inserts into a
>   table containing an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Nevertheless, **two
>   transactions cannot have the AUTO-INC lock on the same table
>   simultaneously, which can have a performance impact if the AUTO-INC
>   lock is held for a long time. That might be the case for a statement
>   such as INSERT INTO t1 ... SELECT ... FROM t2** that inserts all rows
>   from one table into another.

There were some performance improvements in MySQL v5.1.22, which may use a faster method, but there is still some wait between statements.

However, if you aren't using replication, you can improve performance by allowing interleaved auto_increment values which improves performance with concurrency:

> innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2 (“interleaved” lock mode)