# MYSQL - Are inserts with autocommit on, considered a single step or multi step process?

Tags: mysql, insert, atomic

In MYSQL if a conditional insert is performed with autocommit ON, 
ie.

```
set autocommit true;
insert into blah (x,y,z) values (1,2,3) where not exists (.....);
```

Would the above statement be executed atomically and committed at the same time? Or is it possible that there can be a delay between executing the insert and doing the commit?

**EDIT:**
Updated the insert statement to reflect more accurate query:

```
set autocommit true;
insert into foo (x,y,z) select 1,2,3 from dual where not exists (select 1 from bar where a = 1);
```

I want to insert only if a row in another table **does not exist**. What I want to confirm is that in the below scenario there will be a failure:

SESSION1: insert into foo ..... where not exists (select 1 from bar where a = 1);

SESSION2: insert into bar (a) values (1);

SESSION2: commit;

SESSION1: commit; // should fail here.

Comment: What is the rationale behind this question? You would probably need to give a deeper explanation of what you are asking so you do get a precise answer.

Comment: @GMB updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

The way it works is the same as not using autocommit, but you begin a new transaction, immediately do your INSERT, and then immediately COMMIT without delay.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

This is atomic, in the sense that no other client will see your INSERT in a partially-finished state. Atomicity isn't about speed, it's about making sure the change is either committed fully or else not at all. No half-committed state is visible to other sessions.

---

By the way, the syntax you show, `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` is not meaningful. `INSERT` does not have a `WHERE` clause. You may be thinking of an `INSERT` that uses rows output by a `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...;
```

If you do this, you would NOT use a `VALUES()` clause for your `INSERT`.

---

Given your updated question, it cannot work the way you show.

> SESSION1: insert into foo ..... where not exists (select 1 from bar where a = 1);

If you use the default transaction isolation level of REPEATABLE-READ, this will acquire a gap lock on `bar`, where the row where `a=1` would exist. It does this to ensure that there is no change to the latest committed entries in the table that the query was reading.

> SESSION2: insert into bar (a) values (1);

This causes session to wait, because it cannot lock the gap to insert into. It will time out with an error unless Session 1 commits within `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` seconds (default 50).

Comment: Thanks Bill for your response. I have updated my question based on your answer. Please respond accordingly.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068686/how-do-i-lock-on-an-innodb-row-that-doesnt-exist-yet we need to use FOR UPDATE keyword in the select clause to create a lock on a row that is not existing. Also there is a possibility that it might perform a full table lock. Is that true?

Comment: It depends on if your query condition is on an indexed column or not. If yes, it'll create a gap lock. If the column isn't indexed, it'll effectively lock the whole table (including gaps).