# Deadlock found when trying to get lock laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello I have this code on my laravel job

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($data) {
    $record = ProductQuantity::lockForUpdate()
                    ->where([
                        'product_variant_id' => $data->id,
                        'inventory_id' => $data->inventory_id,
                        'outlet_id' => $data->outlet_id
                    ])
                    ->first();

                if ($record) {
                    $record->update([
                        'sumOfAvailableQuantity' => $data->sumOfAvailableQuantity,
                        'averageCostPrice' => $data->averageCostPrice,
                        'totalCostPrice' => $data->totalCostPrice,
                        'purchasedQuantity' => $data->purchasedQuantity,
                        'returnedQuantity' => $data->returnedQuantity,
                        'transferredQuantityTo' => $data->transferredQuantityTo,
                        'transferredQuantityFrom' => $data->transferredQuantityFrom,
                        'adjustedQuantity' => $data->adjustedQuantity,
                        'totalSoldQuantity' => $this->getTotalSoldQuantity($data)
                    ]);
                } else {
                    ProductQuantity::create([
                        'product_variant_id' => $data->id,
                        'inventory_id' => $data->inventory_id,
                        'outlet_id' => $data->outlet_id,
                        'sumOfAvailableQuantity' => $data->sumOfAvailableQuantity,
                        'averageCostPrice' => $data->averageCostPrice,
                        'totalCostPrice' => $data->totalCostPrice,
                        'purchasedQuantity' => $data->purchasedQuantity,
                        'returnedQuantity' => $data->returnedQuantity,
                        'transferredQuantityTo' => $data->transferredQuantityTo,
                        'transferredQuantityFrom' => $data->transferredQuantityFrom,
                        'adjustedQuantity' => $data->adjustedQuantity,
                        'product_id' => $data->product_id,
                        'company_id' => $data->company_id,
                        'totalSoldQuantity' => $this->getTotalSoldQuantity($data)
                    ]);
                    }
                });
```

and there are more than 3 workers handle jobs

so when execute job deadlock occurs

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: select * from product_quantities where (product_variant_id = 140235 and inventory_id = 1117 and outlet_id = 1122) limit 1 for update
```

why deadlock occurs here specially lockForUpdate make another transaction to wait if they request lock on same row

so what I must do here to solve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialization failure: Deadlock found when trying to get lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267653/serialization-failure-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock)

Comment: Read the caveat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601895/does-select-for-update-prevent-other-connections-inserting-when-the-row-is-not)